# How to show full screen calender on webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

Hi i want to show full screen calender on webpage & i want to display the data on the cells of the calendar.Is there any way by which we can use this?
I don't want a date picker.

[image]
Does google calendar APi provide the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://fullcalendar.io/ is a a JavaScript event calendar. Customizable and open source.

Have not tested this myself, but looks like something you could use in this case.

> FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin that provides a full-sized, drag & drop event calendar like the one below. It uses AJAX to fetch events on-the-fly and is easily configured to use your own feed format. It is visually customizable with a rich API.

FullCalendar also got it's [own tag here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fullcalendar) with a couple of thousand questions, which makes it easier to find resources for common tasks.

Comment: can i display custom data on the cells like on a particular date i want show even name

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google search I found [this](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/01/free-jquery-full-screen-calendar-agenda-plugins.html), maybe one of those can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much.Can i show custom data on cells in this calendar like event name on  a particular? date on a cell.

Comment: **JQuery Event Calendar**


_create/update/remove events by drag & drop._


**jquery-frontier-calendar**


has custom events to


**the calendario plugin**


does'nt support custom events afaik


**FullCalendar**


_DISCLAIMER : FullCalendar is great for displaying events, but it isn't a complete solution for event content-management. Beyond dragging an event to a different time/day, you cannot change an event's name or other associated data. It is up to you to add this functionality through FullCalendar's event hooks._